# route or applogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying to get rails routing to "click" and just not getting it

have a project and a task model:

```
class Task
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title,                     :type => String
  has_many :projects
  belongs_to :user
end


class Project

  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title,                     :type => String
  has_and_belongs_to_many           :tasks
  belongs_to                        :user
end
```

I want to "associate" a task with a project
so I have this in the project controller:

```
def connect
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @project.tasks_ids.push(params[:task_id])
  @project.save
  redirect_to project
end
```

with this route:

```
resources :projects do
    match 'connect/:id' => 'projects#connect', :as => :connect, :via => :put
    resources :tasks
end
```

I cant seem to get this to work in the view:

```
 = link_to 'Associate Task', project_connect_path(@task)
```

fails with:

No route matches {:controller=>"projects", :action=>"connect"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources :projects do
  member do
   put :connect
  end
  resources :tasks
end
```

Your path should look like this:

= link_to 'Associate Task', project_connect_path(@project, :task_id => @task.id), :method => :put

Comment: error is now "Called id for nil"   not sure why @task.id is nil

Comment: How are you initializing the variable @task in the controller?

Comment: that was the next problem.. got it sorted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
resources :projects do
member do
 put 'connect'
end
resources :tasks
end
```

or you can write your route above the `resources :projects do ...`
and here is the link, you can read more about routes there: [Rails routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)